# How to vectorize 2 nested for loop with one complex condition in the inner loop?

Tags: octave, vectorization

Octave calculations is too slow specially when you deal with scientific calculations that can span a very very large matrix, even just iterating. I have to vectorize  it to speed up the calculation.

Vectorizing a 1xn matrix would just be easy by following

```
for i = 1:n
  if (a(i) > 5)
    a(i) -= 20
  endif
endfor
```

https://octave.org/doc/v4.0.1/Basic-Vectorization.html

But I dont have any clue when the matrix becomes nxm. My sample code is shown below.

```
segs = 1000000;
r_int = 100;
r_ot = 2000;
x = linspace (0, 1000, segs);
y = linspace (0, -1000, segs);
[xx, yy] = meshgrid (x, y);
circ = xx.*yy;
circ_matrix = zeros(segs,segs);

#this needs vectorization
for j = 1:segs
  for i = 1:segs
    if((r_int<=circ(i,j)) &&(circ(i,j)<=r_ot))
      circ_matrix(i,j)=1;
    endif;
  endfor;
endfor;
```

I have marked the code that needs vectorization

Some things tried:

```
circ_matrix((r_int<=circ) &&(circ<=r_ot))=1;
```

but did not work

Comment: Should 'rint' be replaced by 'r_int' on line 2?

Comment: Do you want $y$ to be negative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rmid = 0.5*(r_int + r_ot); 
rlen = 0.5*(r_ot - r_int);
cc = double(abs(circ - rmid) <= rlen);
```

Comment: It solved it, can you pls provide an explanation?

Comment: As mentioned in the comment below, a boolean is converted in 0 or 1. So the test is checking whether any value in $circ$ belongs to the interval [r_int, r_ot]. Whenever you have a test inside your loop(s) to vectorize, the expression proposed for 'cc' ask Matlab to test on a matrix --- i.e. to vectorize the test. Matlab will perform the tests component-wise.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach is to use the fact that `true` is equal to $1$ and `false` is equal to $0$. If both conditions in the `if` statement are met, the result is $1$, otherwise it's $0$.

````
segs = 1000000;
r_int = 100;
r_ot = 2000;
x = linspace (0, 1000, segs);
y = linspace (0, -1000, segs);
[xx, yy] = meshgrid (x, y);
circ = xx.*yy;

circ_matrix = ( r_int<=circ ) .* ( circ <=r_ot );
```
````

Comment: that worked as well!